# Serve image in Go that was just created

Tags: image, go

I'm creating an image dynamically when one doesn't exist. IE example_t500.jpg when requested would be created from example.jpg. The problem I'm having is displaying the created image when it's requested before a missing image is shown.

Code:

```
package main

import (
        "image/jpeg"
        "net/http"
        "log"
        "os"
        "strings"
        "fmt"
        "strconv"
        resizer "github.com/nfnt/resize"
    )

func WebHandler (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var Path = "../../static/img/photos/2014/11/4/test.jpg"
    ResizeImage(Path, 500)
    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("example_t500.jpg")))
}

func ResizeImage (Path string, Width uint) {
    var ImageExtension = strings.Split(Path, ".jpg")
    var ImageNum       = strings.Split(ImageExtension[0], "/")
    var ImageName      = ImageNum[len(ImageNum)-1]
    fmt.Println(ImageName)
    file, err := os.Open(Path)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    img, err := jpeg.Decode(file)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    file.Close()

    m := resizer.Resize(Width, 0, img, resizer.Lanczos3)

    out, err := os.Create(ImageName + "_t" + strconv.Itoa(int(Width)) + ".jpg")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer out.Close()

    jpeg.Encode(out, m, nil)
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", WebHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

This is my first time trying to use Go and am having trouble rendering the image. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are a few things you need to do.

First, you need to remove this line from your `WebHandler` function:

```
http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("example_t500.jpg")))
```

That's setting up the default serve mux to handle the root route - but you've already done that in your `main` function here:

```
http.HandleFunc("/", WebHandler)
```

So every time you hit the root route, you're effectively just telling the servemux to handle it again .. but differently.

What you want to do.. is set the `Content-Type` header of the response.. then copy the contents of the file to the response stream. Something like this:

```
func WebHandler (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var Path = "../../static/img/photos/2014/11/4/test.jpg"
    ResizeImage(Path, 500)

    img, err := os.Open("example_t500.jpg")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err) // perhaps handle this nicer
    }
    defer img.Close()
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "image/jpeg") // <-- set the content-type header
    io.Copy(w, img)
}
```

Thats the manual version. There's also [http.ServeFile](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeFile).

EDIT:

In response to your comment - if you don't want to write the file at all and just serve it dynamically, then all you need to do is pass the `http.ResponseWriter` to the `Encode` method. `jpeg.Encode` takes an `io.Writer` .. just as `io.Copy` does in my original example:

```
// Pass in the ResponseWriter
func ResizeImage (w io.Writer, Path string, Width uint) {
    var ImageExtension = strings.Split(Path, ".jpg")
    var ImageNum       = strings.Split(ImageExtension[0], "/")
    var ImageName      = ImageNum[len(ImageNum)-1]
    fmt.Println(ImageName)
    file, err := os.Open(Path)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    img, err := jpeg.Decode(file)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    file.Close()

    m := resizer.Resize(Width, 0, img, resizer.Lanczos3)

    // Don't write the file..
    /*out, err := os.Create(ImageName + "_t" + strconv.Itoa(int(Width)) + ".jpg")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer out.Close()*/

    jpeg.Encode(w, m, nil) // Write to the ResponseWriter
}
```

Accept an `io.Writer` in the method .. then encode it to that. You can then call your method like this:

```
func WebHandler (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var Path = "../../static/img/photos/2014/11/4/test.jpg"
    ResizeImage(w, Path, 500) // pass the ResponseWriter in
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Is there a way that I can render the resized image without actually creating it?

Answer (score 1):

The function you are looking for is [http.ServeFile](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeFile). Use that instead of http.Handle in your code.